# Debian multiarch hello:i386 "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Tags: debian, cpu-architecture

I followed the wiki - https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

```shell
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo dpkg --print-architecture
arm64
$ sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386

$ sudo apt install hello:i386
...
Setting up hello:i386 (2.10-3)
$ hello
bash: /usr/bin/hello: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

$ uname -a
Linux palpie 6.1.0-18-arm64 #1 SMP Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) aarch64 GNU/Linux

$ file /usr/bin/hello
/us/bin/hello: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=b603
44835...dec9f for GNU/linux 3.2.0 stripped
448350eaBeabcd86efb46cb3ec52d6bdec9f,
```

Shouldn't this "just work"?

Comment: Without really knowing; you are running "arm64" based hardware and expect "i386" applications to "just work", that is normally not going to work. You need some kind of i386 emulator (i.e. "code interpreter") see: https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation which might give some hints.

Comment: Indeed, as above, this SHOULDN'T "just work", this should NOT work at all. You can add the "X86" (i386) to any X86_64 hardware because it's retro-compatible, NOT to an ARM64.